# Angular 5 Reload and build errors

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

Just a few issues here.

One, when I use browser refresh it reloads back to `/` instead of the route that is loaded prior to the refresh. Below is my routes definition.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingModule, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginModule, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterModule, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardModule, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  { 
    path: 'vendors', 
    component: VendorModule,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      { path: 'new', component: NewVendorModule, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
    ]
  }
]
```

Second, when I try to run `ng build` or simply refresh the page, I get these errors. How do I resolve these issues?

**ERROR:**

```
src/app/app.component.ts(33,14): error TS2339: Property 'companies' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

**REFERENCED CODE BLOCK**

```
sysUser.companies.forEach(function(company){
    if(company.default){
       defaultComp = company;
    }
})
```

**ERROR**

```
src/app/services/users/users.service.ts(23,21): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

**REFERENCED CODE BLOCK**

```
createRootUser(uid: string, company: string, companyName: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).set({
            'companies' : [
          {
            id : company,
            name : companyName
          }
        ]
        }).then(docRef => {
            resolve(docRef.id);
        }).catch(error => {
            reject(error);
        })
    })
  }
```

**UPDATE** **SHARED APP.COMPONENT.TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { UsersService } from './services/users/users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    public firebaseUser : any;
    public systemUser: any;
    public activeCompany: any;

    constructor(public userServ: UsersService, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public afStor: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) {

        const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
        firebase.firestore().settings(settings);

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user) {

                this.firebaseUser = user;
                this.userServ.fetchUser(user.uid).then(sysUser => {
                    this.systemUser = sysUser;
                    var defaultComp : any;
                    sysUser.companies.forEach(function(company){
                        if(company.default){
                            defaultComp = company;
                        }
                    })
                    this.activeCompany = defaultComp;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log('ERROR:', error);
                })

            } else {
                this.firebaseUser = null;
            }
        });

    }

    public sidebarClosed: boolean = true;
    public sidebarSetOne = true;
    public sidebarSetTwo = true;
    public sidebarSetThree = true;

    logOut(): void {
        firebase.auth().signOut();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your `app.component.ts` ?

Comment: check AuthGuardService component it redirect to / due some mistake

Comment: @NuruSalihu, I shared that. Sorry for the long delay.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is going wrong with guard : **AuthGuardService**
There must be something that will be redirecting to root url. It would be more clearer if you will share AuthGuardService code.

For Error in app.component.ts, you can try using following changes

> sysUser.companies.forEach((company:any)=> { 
>   if(company.default){
>   defaultComp
>   = company; } })